# Changing the Chaco table cell background color

Tags: python, cell, background-color, chaco

I want to change the background color of a table cell in chaco but could not succeed yet.I am using TableEditor from traitsui.api and don't could not find its color attribute.Your help and advice would be much appreciated.Following is the related part of the code.

```
colors = ["blue", "red", "yellow", "green",  "black"]
colors_name = ["Batch1", "Batch2", "Batch3", "Batch4",  "Batch5"]

class ColorTable(HasTraits):
    pass      

    color_table = List(Instance(ColorTable))
    color_columns = []
    color_columns.append(ObjectColumn(name="Name"))
    color_columns.append(ObjectColumn(name="Value"))
    color_table_editor=TableEditor(columns=color_columns,
        deletable = True,
        sortable = False,
        sort_model = False,
        show_lines = True,
        editable= False,
        show_column_labels = False)

    def _updateColorTable(self):
        del(self.color_table)
        data = ColorTable()    
        data.Name="Name"
        data.Value="Color"
        self.color_table.append(data)
        for i in range(len(types_name)):
            data = ColorTable()
            #exec('data.Name="'+str(colors_name[i])+'"')
            #exec('data.Value="'+str(colors[i])+'"')
            data.Name=str(colors_name[i])
            data.Value=str(colors[i])
            #data.Value.format.cell_bg_color=[10,10,10]
            self.color_table.append(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the whole column's bgcolor by passing the color when you initialize the ObjectColumn.
ObjectColumn(name="Value", cell_color='red'). But the problem is that I don't know how to set different color for each row yet!
Mahmoud :d

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud.It would help but I am still looking for a color attribute for each single cell